# Add an ID to radio button within Channel Form

Tags: safecracker, pixelandtonic, field-pack

I need to add an ID attribute to a PT Checkbox within Channel Form so I can target it with JS.

Any idea how I can do this?

The standard usage for Channel Form is '{field:my_radio_button}' which doesn't give me the flexibility of adding and ID.

Input appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use channel forms atm but could this not be done using an if statement?
ref docs safecracker ee 2.4

```
{if radio} {options} <label class="checkbox">{option_value}<label
class="checkbox"> <input type="radio" id="{field_name}"
name="{field_name}" value="{option_value}"{checked}> </label>
{/options} {/if}
```

Then use js on the field name

Comment: Hello Matt, Unfortunately the docs don't work when using PT Fieldpack. You add these in Channel Form using the {field:my_radio_button} syntax which gives no scope for adding IDs. I was hoping somebody had encountered and worked around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use your existing simple method of outputting the radio buttons then copy the rendered code and manually add the buttons with whatever you need.

From memory I believe the name attribute is the primary identifier for the field/radio.

Its not perfect but it does work. Obviously if you change your values back end you'll have to ammemd accordingly.

Or, wrap the simple code in a div with an id and use that to target the contents.

Answer (score 0):

PT fields give the option of {option_value} and {option_name}
Provided you've set up your fields with the value and name.

In your field set up you put (on each line)

```
option_1 : Option 1
option_2 : Option 2
etc etc
```

you then have access to those in your templates.
here's an example:

```
{options:event}
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="event[]" value="{option_value}" {checked}><span>{option_name}</span>
    </label>
{/options:event}
```

so for id you'd use:

```
{options:event}
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="event_{option_value}" name="event[]" value="{option_value}" {checked}><span>{option_name}</span>
    </label>
{/options:event}
```

For mine I used checkboxes but the format is the same for radio buttons